# Image doesn't fit to screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image on screen:

```
    image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
    image.name = "leftside1"
    image.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    image.zPosition = 3


    self.addChild(image)
```

Image has w250xh1920 - when I show screen, image not fit to screen, its bigger up and down, but I have set aspectFit in previous scene:

```
 nextScene!.scaleMode = .aspectFit
```

Try aspectFill doesn't solve my problem. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image size to be the size of the scene like this.

```
if let size = nextScene?.size {
    image.size = size
}
```

Here is an example of how you can dynamically calculate the width.

```
if let size = nextScene?.size {
    // Calculate ratio
    let ratio = size.width / size.height
    // Multiple image width by ratio
    let width = image.size.width * ratio
    // Create a new CGSize
    let newSize = CGSize(width: width, height: size.height)

    image.size = newSize
}
```

Comment: Can I set height size of image by height of scene?

Comment: Yes you can, the size property is a CGSize struct so you are able to access width and height individually. Once you have the width and height you can calculate the width of image.

Comment: OK, so I try set size directly to image : image.size.height = (scene?.size.height)!  - now height is like the height of scene, but image is now wider .... how to set width correctly?